# Python multiprocessing - Process a large number of rows simultaneously

Tags: python, optimization, multicore

SO community,

I am struggling with Python multicore programming. Whilst I cannot disclose too many details about the goal of my code, due to the company's information security policy, I'll try to be as specific as I can.

I am developing a code which will evaluate the weekly scores for several people, divided in 5 groups according to their overall scores. I have a fairly large dataframe, composed of dozens of thousands of rows, each one with the player's ID, the considered week (in a nine week period) and his/her score in the given week. On top of that, I have five arrays of indexes so I can loc/iloc the data for selecting people on one of five groups, depending on their scores.

I wrote a serialized version of this code, but it takes well over an hour to run for a small part (some 150k lines) of our data (I'm developing with a small sample, so I can test the code and, once it's A-OK, I can fire it up with the complete dataset). The structure of the serialized code in pythonesque pseudocode:

```
def weekscore(week, ID, players):
    mask(week)
    players.loc[players['player'==ID]
    score = (calculate score)
    return score
```

And then, for all players and all weeks:

```
sc_week = [] 
for play_ID in playerlist:
        for week in np.arange(0,10): # To consider 9 weeks
            sc_week.append(weekscore(week, play_ID, players)
```

i.e., for each player on the list, gets his/her score for the given week and append on a 9-element list, for further processing.

I know this isn't the best way for approaching this problem, but since I was trying to implement a multicore algorithm, I didn't bothered in optimizing this one. After all, this seemed the perfect opportunity to learn an important skill that will be useful later.

Anyway, I tried every single way I could find on SO to implement a multiprocessing algorithm for this problem. The idea is to delegate different player_IDs to different process, so I could greatly cut the total processing time. I have access to 32-core machines, so if I could make this run with 20 cores I would expect the code to run at least 10 times faster, minimum.

But no matter what I implemented, even though the code forks the process into several processes, it still just processes a single player_ID at a time. I monitored the execution through htop on Linux and through task manager on Windows and in both systems, setting a poolsize of 8, 8 subprocesses were created. Then, one of them would spike to 100% of CPU, output something to the screen, then another one would spike to 100%, output to the screen, another process spike to 100% and output and so on. I was expecting all processes to achieve 100%, but I couldn't managed to do this.

The closest I got was with this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    users, primeiro, dados, index_pred_80, intervalos, percents_ = prepara()

    print('Multiprocessing step')
    import multiprocessing as mp
    from multiprocessing import freeze_support
    from functools import partial
    freeze_support()

    pool = mp.Pool(10)
    constparams = partial(perc1, week = week, ID = ID, players = players)
    pool.map(constparams, users)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Calling the function perc1 which is (anonymized for privacy reasons)

```
def perc1(week, ID, players):
    list1 = []
    for week in np.arange(0,10):
        mask(week)
        players.loc[players['player'==ID]

        print('Week = ', week, 'Player ID = ', player_ID)
        score = (calculate score)

        list1.append(score)
    return (lista1)
```

So, after the long post, what is the best way for achieving this goal? What's the best way to delegate batches of IDs for different processes, so each process can churn through a part of the data?

EDIT 1: Fixed small typos.

EDIT 2: I am aware of the limitations of interactive interpreters for multicore Python, so I tested the code in command line both in Windows and Linux, but the behaviour was the same on both cases.